# Using phia package to test interactions with latest version of afex

Tags: r, lm, anova

How can I use the `testInteractions` function from the `phia` package with the latest version of `afex` (`ez.glm`, now `aov_ez`)?

Whilst this worked straightforwardly in v0.3, it is no longer working in v0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd post the solution here, as it had me puzzled for some time why my scripts based on v.03 no longer ran after updating.

The solution is straightforward, the idata (used by `phia`) is no longer output as `model$idata` but is now in `model$Anova$idata`. Amending the `testInteractions` syntax is all that is needed.

**Working example**

```
# Run the old way, to illustrate method
remove.packages('afex')

install.packages("http://www2.uaem.mx/r-mirror/src/contrib/Archive/afex/afex_0.3-42.tar.gz",repos=NULL, type='source')
require(afex)
packageDescription('afex')

data("obk.long")
head(obk.long)

a<-
ez.glm("id", "value", obk.long, within = c("phase", "hour"), print.formula = TRUE, return='full')
a
nice.anova(a$Anova)

#Run a contrast with phia
install.packages('phia')
require('phia')
testInteractions(a$lm, pairwise = "phase", idata=a$idata)

# Now, with the latest afex
detach("package:afex", unload=TRUE)
install.packages('afex')
require(afex)
packageDescription('afex')

b<-aov_ez("id", "value", obk.long, within = c("phase", "hour"), print.formula = TRUE)
b

# This issue here is that no idata comes out of aov_ez in its latest version, so scripts no longer work...
testInteractions(b$lm, pairwise = "phase", idata=b$idata)

# The data is, however, nested in the Anova table...
testInteractions(b$lm, pairwise = "phase", idata=b$Anova$idata)
```